# Plugin ".ignore" does not working after update 2017.2.2

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, gitignore

The following message appears after running IDE and plugin do not works:

[image: Error message]

It started to appear when I've updated idea to v 2017.2.2.

Plugin version was 1.7.6, I've changed it to 2.0.4 from [here](https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore), but nothing changes.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plug-in is [blocked](https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore/issues/408) because of the known performance issues. When the new version of the plug-in with the fix is released, it will start to work again.